Render list for React
I made switchable tabs on React. And I noticed that switching between them causes rendering of all the list items, not just two, how can I fix this?
Is it possible to solve this problem without using the store?
interface ITab {
    click: () => void;
    isActive: boolean;
    children: ReactNode;
}

const Tab: FC<ITab> = ({ click, isActive, children }) => {
    console.log('tab', children);
    return (
        <div onClick={click} className={classNames(styles.tab, { [styles.tabActive]: isActive })}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};

const Tabs = () => {
    const tabs = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE'];
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);
    const getIsActive = (index: number) => activeTab === index;
    return (
        <div className={styles.tabs}>
            {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
                <Tab key={tab} isActive={getIsActive(index)} click={() => setActiveTab(index)}>
                    {tab}
                </Tab>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};


I dont think React has any built-in mechanism to prevent the re-rendering of all components when state changes. Might have to code the logic up. I am guessing using react.memo. I can help code it up but not sure if it would work tbh. because I would have to play with ReactNode which is painful.

You might want to wrap your Tab component in a React.memo()

I tried React.memo, but the result remained the same

//there are two solutions
const Tab = memo(({ click, isActive, children, index }) => {
  console.log(`render`)
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => click(index)}
      style={{ backgroundColor: isActive ? "red" : "green" }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});

const Tabs = () => {
  const tabs = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE"];
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

// With React.memo, when you pass a function, you should always use useCallback. Long story short, a function is an object, not a primitive.
  const changeActiveTab = useCallback((index: number) => setActiveTab(index), [])

  return (
    <div>
      {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
        <Tab
          key={tab}
          isActive={activeTab === index}
          click={changeActiveTab}
          index={index}
        >
          {tab}
        </Tab>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


//I prefer this solution, in my opinion, it’s more efficient.
const Tab = memo(({ setActiveTab, isActive, children, index }) => {
  console.log(`render`)
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => setActiveTab(index)}
      style={{ backgroundColor: isActive ? "red" : "green" }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});

const Tabs = () => {
  const tabs = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE"];
  //The setter will always refer to the same instance (as far as I know :))
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
        <Tab
          key={tab}
          isActive={activeTab === index}
          setActiveTab={setActiveTab}
          index={index}
        >
          {tab}
        </Tab>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

